# Why is the condition used for the trigger never satisfied on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to create simple trigger to ensure the "from" or "to" (database usernames) is equal to current_user, then can delete the record. But its always raises an exception.

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE policy_test (
 id serial not null,
 val varchar not null,
 "from" varchar not null,
 "to" varchar not null
)
```

I give grant to all database users to select, insert, update, delete on table policy_test.
I ensured the "from" and "to" columns are always database username.

I Created a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION can_delete_policy_test()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
BEGIN
  IF NEW."from" = current_user::varchar OR 
  NEW."to" = current_user::varchar THEN
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'You have no permission to delete this record.';
  END IF;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I did this to use trigger on 'policy_test' table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER policy_test_delete_trigger
BEFORE DELETE ON policy_test
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE FUNCTION can_delete_policy_test();
```

Before call the statement, I ensured the connected database username in some record on policy_test table.

Then i called this statement to delete records:

```
DELETE FROM policy_test
WHERE "from" = current_user
OR "to" = current_user;
```

Comment: Why not use the builtin [Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html)?

Comment: This is a DELETE trigger/function change `NEW` to `OLD`. `NEW` is `NULL`  in `DELETE` triggers per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: i know i can enable RLS but i dont know how can i implement this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `NEW`. `NEW` is NULL in a `DELETE` trigger, and returning NULL from a trigger function aborts the operation. You have to look at `OLD."from"` and `OLD."to"` and `RETURN OLD;`.

Answer (score 0):

I used RLS and POLICY to archieve same thing i want.

```
ALTER TABLE policy_test ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON TABLE policy_test TO "employee";

CREATE POLICY select_policy_test ON policy_test
FOR SELECT USING ( "to" = current_user::varchar );

CREATE POLICY delete_policy_test ON policy_test
FOR DELETE USING (
  "from" = current_user::varchar OR
  "to" = current_user::varchar    
);
```